# Conditional elements deleting from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have  matrix, 40x20. I want to delete all the elements less than lets say `a`.

I know how to do it for a column or row using logical indexing:

```
idxToKeep   = yourMat(1, :) <= a;
newMat      = yourMat(:, idxToKeep);
```

But what if the `idxToKeep` I get is also a matrix. I can imagine how to do it using loops, but I don't want to use loop.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
idxToKeep=yourMat<=a;
values=yourMat(idxToKeep);
```

Off course you can do it in one line if you wish:

```
values=yourMat(yourMat<=a);
```

And if you want the output in a matrix format:

```
newMat=yourMat;
newMat(newMat>a)=NaN; %or 0
```

Comment: +1 It should be added that this returns a vector, not a matrix. The matrix shape can't be preserved in the general case with arbitrary entries deleted

Comment: @LuisMendo correct. I added a paragraph to generate a matrix with all elements not matching the criterion set to NaN.